# How to add a JS function in a script block in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to create the below below element and add this to head section of the HTML file.

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
 //Var declarations - ABCCD
        (function(d) {
            //FUNCTION CODES
        }(document));
    </script>
```

Everything is done but I am just getting issue with the above mentioned part. I have tried different options, but not able to add the function as it is mentioned.

```html
var headtg = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var divElm = document.createElement('div');
var scpt = document.createElement('script');
scpt.type = 'text/javascript';

var A = "100";

    var myfunc1 = function(d) {
            //LINES OF CODE
        }(document);

divElm.className = "ABC_" + A;
divElm.appendChild(scpt);
headtg.appendChild(divElm);

//Var declaration part
var decvar = 'var A = 10;'
scpt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(decvar));
    
scpt.innerHTML = myfunc1;
```

But the function is not coming up within the script block and coming up as undefined.

Please help

Comment: hi @CBroe, yes I have created another question as the earlier one put on hold, not sure why

Comment: It's pretty clear why it was put on hold, it states why in a big yellow banner. *Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.
If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please **edit the question**.* If your not careful your may well get a [question ban](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)

Comment: I have already updated the question but its still showing on hold..

Comment: It's still incredibly unclear what your actually asking. You've received **7 answers** none of which seem to answer whatever it is your asking. Ask yourself why does no one understand the question? Your edits (and this question) have not made this any better, that's why it's not been re-opened. Duplicating the same question is still wrong. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to append a jquery script to the top of an html page that I use occassionally.  Rather than injecting the jquery script inject your javascript.

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = 
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
setTimeout(function(){ 
    console.log("Hey jquery");
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to ask, but I think your immediate function is syntactically incorrect, it's written like this

```
(function(param){
    //Do something
})(passed_param);
```

Comment: Yes thats right Anubhav.. but my problem is that I need to add this function within a script block which I am creating in the code.

Comment: What's the problem then?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can figure from your code, the `innerHTML` you are trying to add to the `script` tag is not a **string**, but an function object. You should change it to be between " ".

EDIT:
Also, when you set `tag.innerHTML = "something"`, then all the tag contents will be replaced. In your case, you probably want to add to it instead, so do `tag.innerHTML += "something"`.

Comment: Right but then to add all these function line of codes, I need to write 5/6 lines of innerHTML + code.. Could you please advise if there anyway I can add this function directly into the script block?